# android porting: "service 'SurfaceFlinger' died"

Tags: android, boot, surfaceflinger

I am trying to boot blaze board with jellybean 4AJ.2.5P2. When I am trying to boot, I got the following error.

```
init: Failed to open socket 'property_service': Address family not supported by protocol
```

I have used the below bootargs:

```
setenv bootargs 'console=ttyO2,115200n8 mem=1G androidboot.console=ttyO2 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rw rootdelay=2 rootfstype=ext3 init=/init vram=32M omapfb.vram=0:16M androidboot.console=ttyO2 consoleblank=0'
setenv bootcmd 'mmcinit 0;fatload mmc 0 0x80000000 uImage; bootm 0x80000000'
boot
```

These are the log which i got.

```
[    3.341949] cannot apply mgr(lcd2) on inactive device
[    3.384948] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 160x48
[    3.438201] cannot apply mgr(lcd2) on inactive device
[    3.443969] cannot aply mgr(lcd)--invalid device
[    3.449310] omapfb omapfb: failed to apply dispc config
[    3.455230] cannot aply mgr(tv)--invalid device
[    3.460418] omapfb omapfb: failed to apply dispc config
[    3.466674] cannot apply mgr(lcd2) on inactive device
[    3.473510] omapfb omapfb: failed to apply dispc config
[    3.481842] omapdss DPI: Could not find exact pixel clock. Requested 71000 kHz, got 69818 kHz
[    3.497100] VUSB: incomplete constraints, leaving on
[    3.504638] twl_rtc twl_rtc: setting system clock to 2000-01-01 00:00:00 UTC (946684800)
[    3.514099] ALSA device list:
[    3.517669]   No soundcards found.
[    3.522155] Waiting 2sec before mounting root device...
[    5.576232] kjournald starting.  Commit interval 5 seconds
[    5.580352] EXT3-fs (mmcblk0p2): using internal journal
[    5.582672] EXT3-fs (mmcblk0p2): recovery complete
[    5.582702] EXT3-fs (mmcblk0p2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode
[    5.582763] VFS: Mounted root (ext3 filesystem) on device 179:2.
[    5.583251] Freeing init memory: 272K
[    5.616943] init (1): /proc/1/oom_adj is deprecated, please use /proc/1/oom_score_adj instead.
[    5.802490] init: could not open /dev/keychord
[    5.808410] init: cannot open '/initlogo.rle'
[    6.206970] rproc remoteproc0: skipping power up until last virtio device ipu_c0
[    6.217071] virtio_rpmsg_bus virtio0: rpmsg host is online
[    6.223083] init: Failed to open socket 'property_service': Address family not supported by protocol
[    6.223602] init: init startup failure
[    6.223999] Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000100
```

I have searched a lot, i couldn't find anything useful.

Any help will be appreciated!

Thank you!

**UPDATE:**

We had changed lot in kernel. Now the above mentioned errors are no more. But, I am facing the problem in surface flinger.

When Surface flinger is started, crash is occurred and at last, logcat shows that "service 'SurfaceFlinger' died"

I've attached the recent logs below.

```
--------- beginning of /dev/log/main
I/installd(   94): installd firing up
E/uim-sysfs(   86): uim: Inside main
E/uim-sysfs(   86): uim:BT/FM/GPS would be unavailable on system
I/DEBUG   (   89): debuggerd: Nov 21 2013 17:58:24
--------- beginning of /dev/log/system
I/Vold    (   83): Vold 2.1 (the revenge) firing up
D/Vold    (   83): Volume sdcard state changing -1 (Initializing) -> 0 (No-Media)
D/Vold    (   83): Volume usbflash1 state changing -1 (Initializing) -> 0 (No-Media)
D/Vold    (   83): Volume usbflash2 state changing -1 (Initializing) -> 0 (No-Media)
I/Netd    (   88): Netd 1.0 starting
W/InterfaceController(   88): Warning (Cannot load library: load_library(linker.cpp:745): library "/system/lib/libnetcmdiface.so" not found) while opening the net interface coy
V/IMGSRV  (   84): Succesfully loaded gfx modules
V/IMGSRV  (   84): pvrsrvinit complete
I/SurfaceFlinger(   90): SurfaceFlinger is starting
I/SurfaceFlinger(   90): SurfaceFlinger's main thread ready to run. Initializing graphics H/W...
I/libEGL  (   90): Processor type: omap4460
I/libEGL  (   90): egl.cfg: entry POWERVR_SGX540_120 omap4430
I/libEGL  (   90): egl.cfg: entry POWERVR_SGX540_120 omap4460
I/libEGL  (   90): Picked EGL type 'POWERVR_SGX540_120' for processor 'omap4460'
D/libEGL  (   90): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
D/MDnsDS  (   88): MDnsSdListener starting to monitor
D/MDnsDS  (   88): MDnsSdListener::Hander starting up
D/MDnsDS  (   88): Going to poll with pollCount 1
D/libEGL  (   90): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
D/libEGL  (   90): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
I/mediaserver(   93): ServiceManager: 0x410ffe80
I/AudioFlinger(   93): Using default 3000 mSec as standby time.
I/CameraService(   93): CameraService started (pid=93)
E/SurfaceFlinger(   90): framebuffer_open for fb1 failed (Invalid argument)
E/SurfaceFlinger(   90): composer device failed to initialize (No such device)
I/SurfaceFlinger(   90): Using composer version 1.1
W/SurfaceFlinger(   90): no suitable EGLConfig found, trying without EGL_FRAMEBUFFER_TARGET_ANDROID
E/BufferQueue(   90): [FramebufferSurface] setDefaultBufferSize: dimensions cannot be 0 (w=0, h=0)
I/SurfaceFlinger(   90): EGL informations:
I/SurfaceFlinger(   90): vendor    : Android
I/SurfaceFlinger(   90): version   : 1.4 Android META-EGL
I/SurfaceFlinger(   90): extensions: EGL_KHR_image EGL_KHR_image_base EGL_KHR_gl_texture_2D_image EGL_KHR_gl_texture_cubemap_image EGL_KHR_gl_renderbuffer_image EGL_KHR_fence_ 
I/SurfaceFlinger(   90): Client API: OpenGL_ES
I/SurfaceFlinger(   90): EGLSurface: 8-8-8-8, config=0x2
I/SurfaceFlinger(   90): OpenGL ES informations:
I/SurfaceFlinger(   90): vendor    : Imagination Technologies
I/SurfaceFlinger(   90): renderer  : PowerVR SGX 540
I/SurfaceFlinger(   90): version   : OpenGL ES-CM 1.1
I/SurfaceFlinger(   90): extensions: GL_EXT_debug_marker GL_OES_byte_coordinates GL_OES_fixed_point GL_OES_single_precision GL_OES_matrix_get GL_OES_read_format GL_OES_comprest
I/SurfaceFlinger(   90): GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE = 2048
I/SurfaceFlinger(   90): GL_MAX_VIEWPORT_DIMS = 2048 x 2048
D/SurfaceFlinger(   90): Screen acquired, type=0 flinger=0x40af9318
F/libc    (   90): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000800 (code=1), thread 260 (SurfaceFlinger)
E/CameraHal(   93): (400cd3dc)   hardware/ti/omap4xxx/camera/OMXCameraAdapter/OMXDCC.cpp:99 initDCC - No DCC files found, switching back to default DCC
E/CameraHal(   93): (400cd3dc)   hardware/ti/omap4xxx/camera/OMXCameraAdapter/OMXDCC.cpp:44 loadDCC -  Error in DCC Init
D/DOMX    (   93): hardware/ti/domx/domx/omx_proxy_common/src/omx_proxy_common.c:1671   __PROXY_SetConfig()
D/DOMX    (   93): ERROR: failed check:(eError == OMX_ErrorNone) || (eError == OMX_ErrorNoMore) - returning error: 0x80001009 - Error returned from OMX API in ducati
E/CameraHal(   93): (400cd3dc)   hardware/ti/omap4xxx/camera/BaseCameraAdapter.cpp:2708 CameraAdapter_Capabilities - supportedCameras= 0
E/CameraHal(   93): (400cd3dc)   hardware/ti/omap4xxx/camera/CameraProperties.cpp:108 loadProperties - camera busy. properties not loaded. num_cameras = 0
E/CameraHal(   93): (400cd3dc)   hardware/ti/omap4xxx/camera/CameraHal_Module.cpp:770 camera_get_number_of_cameras - Unable to create or initialize CameraProperties
I/AudioPolicyManagerBase(   93): loadAudioPolicyConfig() loaded /system/etc/audio_policy.conf
I/AudioFlinger(   93): loadHwModule() Loaded primary audio interface from Default audio HW HAL (audio) handle 1
I/AudioFlinger(   93): HAL output buffer size 1024 frames, normal mix buffer size 1024 frames
W/EffectsFactory(   93): loadLibrary() failed to open /system/lib/soundfx/libdseffect.so
W/EffectsFactory(   93): loadEffect() could not get library ds
I/AudioMixer(   93): found effect "Multichannel Downmix To Stereo" from The Android Open Source Project
I/AudioFlinger(   93): Using module 1 has the primary audio interface
I/AudioFlinger(   93): AudioFlinger's thread 0x41102a58 ready to run
W/AudioFlinger(   93): Thread AudioOut_2 cannot connect to the power manager service
W/AudioFlinger(   93): Thread AudioOut_2 cannot connect to the power manager service
I/AudioFlinger(   93): HAL output buffer size 1024 frames, normal mix buffer size 1024 frames
I/AudioMixer(   93): found effect "Multichannel Downmix To Stereo" from The Android Open Source Project
I/AudioFlinger(   93): AudioFlinger's thread 0x4110d6e8 ready to run
W/AudioFlinger(   93): Thread AudioOut_3 cannot connect to the power manager service
E/AudioFlinger(   93): int android::load_audio_interface(char const*, audio_hw_device_t**) couldn't load audio hw module audio.hdmi (No such file or directory)
I/AudioFlinger(   93): loadHwModule() error -2 loading module hdmi 
W/AudioPolicyManagerBase(   93): could not open HW module hdmi
I/audio_a2dp_hw(   93): adev_open:  adev_open in A2dp_hw module
I/AudioFlinger(   93): loadHwModule() Loaded a2dp audio interface from A2DP Audio HW HAL (audio) handle 4
I/r_submix(   93): adev_open(name=audio_hw_if)
I/r_submix(   93): adev_init_check()
I/AudioFlinger(   93): loadHwModule() Loaded r_submix audio interface from Wifi Display audio HAL (audio) handle 5
I/AudioPolicyService(   93): Loaded audio policy from LEGACY Audio Policy HAL (audio_policy)
I/DEBUG   (   89): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG   (   89): Build fingerprint: 'Android/svdu/svdu:4.2.2/JDQ39/eng.build.20131121.165220:userdebug/test-keys'
I/DEBUG   (   89): Revision: '0'
I/DEBUG   (   89): pid: 90, tid: 260, name: SurfaceFlinger  >>> /system/bin/surfaceflinger <<<
I/DEBUG   (   89): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000800
I/DEBUG   (   89):     r0 40859390  r1 00000000  r2 00000000  r3 00000800
I/DEBUG   (   89):     r4 40af9318  r5 00000000  r6 400cadc8  r7 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   89):     r8 4017f1f6  r9 00000001  sl 40af955c  fp 00000009
I/DEBUG   (   89):     ip 400d7f80  sp 404e3c40  lr 400c187d  pc 00000800  cpsr 40000110
I/DEBUG   (   89):     d0  3831333966613034  d1  707974202c646572
I/DEBUG   (   89):     d2  47207463656a6272  d3  5f454c5050415f65
I/DEBUG   (   89):     d4  0000000080000000  d5  0000000100000000
I/DEBUG   (   89):     d6  000000013f800000  d7  3f8000003f800000
I/DEBUG   (   89):     d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   89):     d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   89):     d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   89):     d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   89):     d16 0000000000000001  d17 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   89):     d18 0000000000000000  d19 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   89):     d20 0000000000000000  d21 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   89):     d22 0000000000000000  d23 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   89):     d24 0000000000000000  d25 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   89):     d26 0000000000000000  d27 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   89):     d28 0000000000000000  d29 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   89):     d30 0000000000000000  d31 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   89):     scr 60000010
I/DEBUG   (   89): 
I/DEBUG   (   89): backtrace:
I/DEBUG   (   89):     #00  pc 00000800  <unknown>
I/DEBUG   (   89):     #01  pc 0002387b  /system/lib/libsurfaceflinger.so (android::HWComposer::acquire(int)+10)
I/DEBUG   (   89):     #02  pc 000266bf  /system/lib/libsurfaceflinger.so (android::SurfaceFlinger::onScreenAcquired(android::sp<android::DisplayDevice const> const&)+74)
I/DEBUG   (   89):     #03  pc 000288fb  /system/lib/libsurfaceflinger.so (android::SurfaceFlinger::onInitializeDisplays()+154)
I/DEBUG   (   89):     #04  pc 00028929  /system/lib/libsurfaceflinger.so
I/DEBUG   (   89):     #05  pc 000247c7  /system/lib/libsurfaceflinger.so (android::MessageBase::handleMessage(android::Message const&)+12)
I/DEBUG   (   89):     #06  pc 00014c53  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollInner(int)+426)
I/DEBUG   (   89):     #07  pc 00014d71  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*, void**)+104)
I/DEBUG   (   89):     #08  pc 00024b55  /system/lib/libsurfaceflinger.so (android::MessageQueue::waitMessage()+40)
I/DEBUG   (   89):     #09  pc 00025145  /system/lib/libsurfaceflinger.so (android::SurfaceFlinger::threadLoop()+6)
I/DEBUG   (   89):     #10  pc 00011267  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+114)
I/DEBUG   (   89):     #11  pc 00010dcd  /system/lib/libutils.so
I/DEBUG   (   89):     #12  pc 0000e3e8  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
I/DEBUG   (   89):     #13  pc 0000dad4  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+160)
I/DEBUG   (   89): 
I/DEBUG   (   89): stack:
I/DEBUG   (   89):          404e3c00  40af9490  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   89):          404e3c04  4017a3c7  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::SortedVectorImpl::_indexOrderOf(void const*, unsigned int*) const+50)
I/DEBUG   (   89):          404e3c08  409aeeac  
I/DEBUG   (   89):          404e3c0c  40af9318  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   89):          404e3c10  404e3c60  [stack:260]
I/DEBUG   (   89):          404e3c14  400c8595  /system/lib/libsurfaceflinger.so (android::SurfaceFlinger::setTransactionState(android::Vector<android::ComposerState> const&, )
I/DEBUG   (   89):          404e3c18  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   89):          404e3c1c  4017f1f6  /system/lib/libutils.so
I/DEBUG   (   89):          404e3c20  409aee90  
I/DEBUG   (   89):          404e3c24  409b41d8  
I/DEBUG   (   89):          404e3c28  404e3c60  [stack:260]
I/DEBUG   (   89):          404e3c2c  73e76319  
I/DEBUG   (   89):          404e3c30  40af9318  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   89):          404e3c34  404e3c60  [stack:260]
I/DEBUG   (   89):          404e3c38  df0027ad  
I/DEBUG   (   89):          404e3c3c  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     #00  404e3c40  00000001  
I/DEBUG   (   89):          ........  ........
I/DEBUG   (   89):     #01  404e3c40  00000001  
I/DEBUG   (   89):          404e3c44  400c46c3  /system/lib/libsurfaceflinger.so (android::SurfaceFlinger::onScreenAcquired(android::sp<android::DisplayDevice const> const&)+7)
I/DEBUG   (   89):     #02  404e3c48  40af9318  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   89):          404e3c4c  404e3c60  [stack:260]
I/DEBUG   (   89):          404e3c50  404e3c8c  [stack:260]
I/DEBUG   (   89):          404e3c54  40af9318  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   89):          404e3c58  400c8595  /system/lib/libsurfaceflinger.so (android::SurfaceFlinger::setTransactionState(android::Vector<android::ComposerState> const&, )
I/DEBUG   (   89):          4[   16.940643] init: Boot Animation exit
04e3c5c  400c68ff  /system/lib/libsurfaceflinger.so (android::Su[   16.949279] binder: undelivered death notification, 40673840
rfaceFlinger::onInitializeDisplays()+158)
I/DEBUG   (   89): 
I/DEBUG   (   89): memory near r0:
I/DEBUG   (   89):     40859370 0049002e 00530044 00570053 00480042  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     40859380 006c0061 00000000 00000000 0000005b  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     40859390 00000000 00000000 00000001 40af9630  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     408593[   16.986175] init: untracked pid 405 exited
a0 00000000 00000001 404f8014 40859510  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     408593b0 40868008 00000000 00000008 00000008  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     408593c0 00000008 00000008 00000020 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     408593d0 00000000 00000002 00000800 00000800  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     408593e0 00000001 0000002b 00000001 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     408593f0 00000000 0000003c 404f53e8 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     40859400 00000000 00000000 00003038 0000002b  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     40859410 00000001 00000000 00000000 0000000c  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     40859420 404f54dc 00000000 00000000 408593e8  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     40859430 40123d5c 0000002b 00000001 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     40859440 00000000 00000004 404f5534 00000000  
[   17.056304] init: untracked pid 400 exited
I/DEBUG   (   89):     40859450 00000000 40859410 404f54dc 0000002b  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     40859460 00000001 00000001 00000020 0000001c  
I/DEBUG   (   89): 
I/DEBUG   (   89): memory near r4:
I/DEBUG   (   89):     40af92f8 00630100 00000000 00000161 00670001  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     40af9308 4028fa70 409b5d10 00000038 0000021b  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     40af9318 400d150c 400d1580 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     40af9328 400d15d0 400d15e8 00000000 40af9630  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     40af9338 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000100  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     40af9348 00000000 00000104 400d1608 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     40af9358 400d1448 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     40af9368 00000004 400d0ee0 409e8470 00000001  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     40af9378 00000000 00000040 ffffffff 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     40af9388 400d29bc 40124228 400d1a10 bed33b10  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     40af9398 00000000 00000000 00000000 40af9318  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     40af93a8 400d1a14 000000df 40af5030 00000018  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     40af93b8 00000000 00000000 400d0c60 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     40af93c8 00000000 00000000 00000004 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     40af93d8 400ce8c0 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     40af93e8 00000004 00000000 00000000 40854dc0  
I/DEBUG   (   89): 
I/DEBUG   (   89): memory near r6:
I/DEBUG   (   89):     400cada8 7fffe88e 00001e04 7fffe898 00001e08  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     400cadb8 7fffe96c 8007aab0 7fffeca8 00000001  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     400cadc8 66727553 46656361 676e696c 50007265  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     400cadd8 696d7265 6f697373 6544206e 6c61696e  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     400cade8 6163203a 2074276e 6e65706f 626f6c47  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     400cadf8 72546c61 61736e61 6f697463 6970206e  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     400cae08 64253d64 6975202c 64253d64 74656700  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     400cae18 6579614c 65735572 616e2872 253d656d  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     400cae28 69202964 65642073 61006461 6f72646e  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     400cae38 702e6469 696d7265 6f697373 43412e6e  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     400cae48 53534543 5255535f 45434146 494c465f  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     400cae58 5245474e 204c4700 6f727265 78302072  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     400cae68 78343025 6c676500 70617753 66667542  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     400cae78 28737265 202c7025 20297025 6c696166  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     400cae88 77206465 20687469 30257830 42007838  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     400cae98 746c6975 206e692d 65726353 48006e65  
I/DEBUG   (   89): 
I/DEBUG   (   89): memory near r8:
I/DEBUG   (   89):     4017f1d4 20746f67 6e727265 64253d6f 206e6f20  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     4017f1e4 27732527 6572000a 746c7573 203d2120  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     4017f1f4 6f4c0030 7265706f 756f4300 6e20646c  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     4017f204 6120746f 636f6c6c 20657461 20534c54  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     4017f214 2e79656b 756f4300 6e20646c 6320746f  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     4017f224 74616572 61772065 7020656b 2e657069  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     4017f234 72652020 3d6f6e72 43006425 646c756f  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     4017f244 746f6e20 6b616d20 61772065 7220656b  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     4017f254 20646165 65706970 6e6f6e20 6f6c622d  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     4017f264 6e696b63 20202e67 6e727265 64253d6f  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     4017f274 756f4300 6e20646c 6d20746f 20656b61  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     4017f284 656b6177 69727720 70206574 20657069  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     4017f294 2d6e6f6e 636f6c62 676e696b 6520202e  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     4017f2a4 6f6e7272 0064253d 6f70456d 64466c6c  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     4017f2b4 30203c20 756f4300 6e20646c 6320746f  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     4017f2c4 74616572 70652065 206c6c6f 74736e69  
I/DEBUG   (   89): 
I/DEBUG   (   89): memory near sl:
I/DEBUG   (   89):     40af953c 00000000 00000000 00000073 40181bd8  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     40af954c 40af95b8 00000001 00000009 0000000a  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     40af955c 00000000 40181a18 409e8330 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     40af956c 00000000 00000010 00000001 0000000b  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     40af957c 40181a60 409b5c28 00000001 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     40af958c 00000014 40181ad0 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     40af959c 00000000 00000014 00000000 ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     40af95ac 7fffffff 00000000 0000001b 00000001  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     40af95bc 00000001 40af9548 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     40af95cc 0000001b 400d0b3c 40af94dc 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     40af95dc 400d0b64 40af95e8 0000001b 00000001  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     40af95ec 00000001 40af95dc 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     40af95fc 00000013 40afa6a8 40af9620 404e5fbc  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     40af960c 00000023 00000001 00000009 66727553  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     40af961c 46656361 70616d6f 30363434 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     40af962c 00000043 4009d3dc 409b5b18 00000001  
I/DEBUG   (   89): 
I/DEBUG   (   89): memory near ip:
I/DEBUG   (   89):     400d7f60 00000000 00000000 400fa741 400fa631  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     400d7f70 400e6748 400f4d73 400efe38 400e6c78  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     400d7f80 400f0024 400e7ef9 400f0568 400f1988  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     400d7f90 40111b93 400f2540 400fa27d 400eb781  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     400d7fa0 400f7a5d 400f1890 400f107c 400f1610  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     400d7fb0 400f6615 400e5f2d 400e5f19 400fe021  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     400d7fc0 400fe041 400fe1a7 400f66d5 40100db1  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     400d7fd0 40101ba1 40111c7c 400e5f05 400fe001  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     400d7fe0 400fe0d9 400efd98 400efed4 400f1c89  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     400d7ff0 400efe54 400f4d33 400fd609 400fad57  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     400d8000 400d8000 00000004 00000005 00000006  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     400d8010 00000007 400d5089 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     400d8020 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     400d8030 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     400d8040 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     400d8050 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   89): 
I/DEBUG   (   89): memory near sp:
I/DEBUG   (   89):     404e3c20 409aee90 409b41d8 404e3c60 73e76319  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     404e3c30 40af9318 404e3c60 df0027ad 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     404e3c40 00000001 400c46c3 40af9318 404e3c60  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     404e3c50 404e3c8c 40af9318 400c8595 400c68ff  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     404e3c60 409b2b78 400d0fc0 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     404e3c70 00000000 00000060 400d1008 409e8388  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     404e3c80 00000001 00000000 00000034 00000004  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     404e3c90 409aee90 00000000 00000001 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     404e3ca0 00000000 00000000 ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     404e3cb0 00000000 00000000 ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     404e3cc0 40af9560 409b5c80 409b5c84 400c27bb  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     404e3cd0 40af9560 400c692d 400d165c 400c27c9  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     404e3ce0 400d165c 40af9548 00000000 4017cc55  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     404e3cf0 00100000 00000014 00100000 642f0001  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     404e3d00 00000001 40af9590 0000287d 000028aa  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     404e3d10 735f7974 409b5c80 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   89): 
I/DEBUG   (   89): code around pc:
I/DEBUG   (   89):     000007e0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     000007f0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     00000800 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     00000810 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     00000820 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     00000830 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     00000840 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     00000850 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     00000860 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     00000870 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     00000880 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     00000890 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     000008a0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     000008b0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     000008c0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     000008d0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (   89): 
I/DEBUG   (   89): code around lr:
I/DEBUG   (   89):     400c185c 0100f8d4 d3e84285 e8bd4638 bf0083f8  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     400c186c 01010001 68c0b508 6cc3b110 47982200  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     400c187c 2900bd08 dd09b530 4500f04f 4118f8d0  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     400c188c 422540cd f06fd105 bd30004a 004af06f  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     400c189c 2448bd30 31284361 50421844 60632000  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     400c18ac f8842301 bd303020 b5102900 480fdc14  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     400c18bc 4478490f e0034479 490f480e 44794478  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     400c18cc f7f82200 f7f9ed5e 2300e934 63a362a3  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     400c18dc f88463e3 bd103020 dced2902 fb042448  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     400c18ec 34280401 28006aa0 bd10d1ed 00009e7b  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     400c18fc 00009504 00009e99 000094fa 4604b510  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     400c190c b12868c0 f7ff4904 b108f8d9 bd102005  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     400c191c 6d186863 bf00bd10 01010001 b11068c0  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     400c192c f7ff4901 4770b8cb 01010001 41f0e92d  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     400c193c 68c04604 4617460d b1c8461e f7ff490e  
I/DEBUG   (   89):     400c194c b1a8f8bd 46294620 4633463a 41f0e8bd  
D/skia    (   91): SkGraphics::Init() - BLTsville (CPU) dlopen success
D/AndroidRuntime(   91): 
D/AndroidRuntime(   91): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit <<<<<<
D/AndroidRuntime(   91): CheckJNI is OFF
I/ServiceManager(   82): service 'SurfaceFlinger' died
W/SurfaceComposerClient(  355): ComposerService remote (surfaceflinger) died [0x415f94d8]
D/BootAnimation(  355): SurfaceFlinger died, exiting...
D/skia    (  382): SkGraphics::Init() - BLTsville (CPU) dlopen success
D/AndroidRuntime(  382): 
D/AndroidRuntime(  382): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit <<<<<<
D/AndroidRuntime(  382): CheckJNI is OFF
D/dalvikvm(  382): Unable to stat classpath element '/system/framework/ds.jar'
D/dalvikvm(  382): Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
D/dalvikvm(  382): Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
D/dalvikvm(  382): Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
D/dalvikvm(  382): Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
I/SamplingProfilerIntegration(  382): Profiling disabled.
```

Please help me to debug it.

Any Guidance will be appreciated!!

Comment: Seems to be crashing in `android::HWComposer::acquire(int)`, probably due to the earlier failure to initialize the device ("framebuffer_open for fb1 failed").  Something isn't right with the display device.

Comment: Thank you for your response. DO you know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my Nexus 7 AOSP build.
Its was an LOL moment for me after spending 2 days behind this issue.
I hope this will help you in your journey of building ROM using AOSP for android devices.
You are missing some proprietary binaries required to run hardware components used by devices. Those lib are not built by using AOSP make command. 
Those binaries can be found here: https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/drivers#flo. Make sure your binaries are for the correct Android version you're building (5.1.1 in my case).
Extract the downloaded files into the root of your working directory. Run the extracted scripts and go through the included terms of agreement. You will get some files like "extract-***.sh" in you home directory, run them one by one like

```
$ ./extract-****-**.sh**
run make command again.
```

hope this will take care of the issue you have.

Happy coding.